# "I would argue that studying abroad helps you learn about what's around you"

Tags: translation

A friend of mine recently gave me this argument -

> "最近、多くの学生が自分探しの旅と称して、海外留学しているが、そういう人に限って目標が明確ではないので、何も得られず帰国する人も大勢いる。"
>
> "Recently, many students are claiming to go on a trip to find themselves by studying abroad, however these people fail to define a clear goal, so don't acquire anything when they return to their home country."

I want to reply with this argument -

> "I would argue that studying abroad helps you learn about what's around you, and helps to understand things other than what you are familiar with. It helps you gain new ideas and perspectives."
>
> "海外留学は 人の周辺の理解に 論陣を張って、慣れること以外をわかってくれます。フレッシュな考えと見る目をくれます。"

Does the last sentence make sense? I'm concerned about the use of "argue" and 論陣を張って and 人の周辺の理解.

Comment: Xに論陣を張る means "to campaign against X". わかってくれる means "they thankfully understand".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid I couldn't comprehend your sentences if it were not for your translation.

- "argue"

  - You can't 論陣を張る unless you put out an argument with a firm and resolute manner and intensive research. It's such a big word.
  - Usually we argue something using ～と思う or ～と考える (formally). That's why many Japanese overuse "I think" in English :)
  - I guess that the object of "argue" should be everything after it before "... familiar with.", or perhaps before "... and perspectives." Thus you should put the verb at the end of them to make sense of it.
- "helps..., and helps..."

  - If you intend them to be parallel clauses (as opposed to serial "A, then B" connection), we usually use ～たり～たり construction.
  - くれる is indeed a good choice to translate "helps you" (while *you* is generic, but proximately assumed to be the hearer).
  - But Japanese language dislikes the idea of "*inanimate thing* helps *animate thing*". In order to make it natural, you should rephrase it with human perspective like "you can do... with..." etc, or at least avoid "you" standing as object.
- "learn"

  - Better 知る or 学ぶ.
- "what's around you"

  - Japanese doesn't have a *preposition* "around" but *noun* equivalents. You can just omit this generic "you" because it's grammatically unrequired.
  - If you retain "you", it should be 自分 or その人. 人 would mean "others".
  - 周り or 周囲 (surroundings) would be more appropriate than 周辺 (periphery).
- "familiar with"

  - 慣れる is "*get* used to"; "*be* used to" is 慣れている, or 慣れた (as a participle).
  - "Be familiar with" is more like なじみのある or よく知っている etc.
- "understand"

  - Better 理解する.
- "ideas and perspectives"

  - It's open to many interpretations, but 考えと見る目 "thoughts and discernment(?)" sound a bit odd.
  - We use や for this "and".

In my own Japanese (I don't know if this is perfectly in keeping with your intentions):

> 海外留学は、周りの環境について学んだり、今まで見たことのない物事を理解（したり）して、新しい考え方や視点を得る（ための）良い機会なんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the enlightening post! It sounds like some intensive study is going to be required for me to connect all the dots with grammar I've learned and to fully understand advanced vocab, since what I wrote seems to be completely wrong, I'm probably overreaching with this type of language right now.

Comment: (1) If you keep original sense of "things other than what you are familiar with", you can go with よく知っている(こと)以外のこと or so. (2) Another way to convert transitivity of（海外留学は…を得ることを）助けてくれる is …を得る 助け に なる.